# How do I join two queries into one using table join

Tags: sql

This is my first query using table join of two tables sharing the same primary key:

```
select s.Branch_ID, count(s.Branch_ID)  'No. of Staff', BranchName 'Branch Name'
from Sales_Staff s , Branch b
where s.Branch_ID = b.Branch_ID
group by s.Branch_ID, BranchName
order by 2 desc
```

[image: Here is an image of how the output looks like]

This is the second query:

```
select p.Branch_ID, BranchName, Count(p.Branch_ID) 'Frequency of Packages bought'
from Payment p, Branch b
where p.Branch_ID = b.Branch_ID
Group by p.Branch_ID, BranchName
```

[image: Here's how the second one looks like]

Now, the output for both was what I expected and wanted. However when I use the same method to join those two queries, the numbers are wrong.

```
select p.Branch_ID, BranchName, Count(p.Branch_ID) 'Frequency of Packages bought', count(s.Branch_ID) 'No. of Staff'
from Payment p, Sales_Staff s, Branch b
where p.Branch_ID = s.Branch_ID
and s.Branch_ID = b.Branch_ID
Group by b.Branch_ID, p.Branch_ID, BranchName
```

Incorrect Output
[image: Incorrect Output]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Very difficult to read when you don't include your output inline with the question.

Comment: It's because your `SELECT` statenent produce the Cartesian product of rows of the tables. To join rows by a key you need to use [`JOIN` clause](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) instead.

Comment: Removed conflicting product tags. Pls add the one back that you use.

Comment: OP does have a join clause, just the old fashion version using "where" between the tables. But its the nature of the join that's wrong. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to do the two group by's separately as you are getting many to many joins - every staff for every payment for each branch.

```
select  b.BranchID, b.BranchName, isnull(s.StaffCount,0) as StaffCount, isnull(p.PackageCount,0) as PackageCount
from    Branch b
left join (select Branch_ID, count(*) as StaffCount from SaleStaff group by Branch_ID) s on s.Branch_ID = b.Branch_ID
left join (select Branch_ID, count(*) as PackageCount from Payment group by Branch_ID) p on p.Branch_ID = b.Branch_ID
```